# In Greg Bear's novel Moving Mars, what is the name of the Turing-test-like test they used to validate artificial intelligences?

Tags: novel, artificial-intelligence, greg-bear

It's a test developed by some fictional psychologist and named after the same (like the Turing Test). In the same vein as Voigt-Kampf I suppose, but AIs eventually managed to pass even this test too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't know if the link will work for you, but looking it up in Google Books gave me [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=OhKV8foHFGkC&pg=PA213&lpg=PA213&dq=moving+mars+turing+test&source=bl&ots=QXM4ToL7gx&sig=sIAglH-KgaWs-_pUi-7NGQ9tqvA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=N4QAULqpF4ns0gGY6JWhBw&ved=0CE8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=moving%20mars%20turing%20test&f=false).

> Jill was the oldest thinking being on Earth, a fabulous figure, the first thinker to achieve bona fide self-awareness, as defined by the **Atkins test**.
>
> Decades before Jill and Roger Atkins, Alan Turing had proposed the Turing test for equality between human and machine...